# DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN Subdomain and Domain Issue

Tags: wordpress, dns, subdomain

I have a basic wordpress website with a few simple plugins such as gravityforms etc. For the sake of this question the site has a domain of domain.com
To manage user input we have another system on a subdomain, sub.domain.com

Some users are intermittently receiving the following error 'DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN' whether that be on the domain or subdomain.
Is it possible that this issue is an issue on one of domain.com or sub.domain.com and the users browser shows errors with both purely because the urls have the same domain?

Comment: Yes, it is possible.

Answer (score 1):

Add wildcard DNS on cpanel. You can create wildcard dns following instruction on the below.

http://www.webhostinghub.com/help/learn/cpanel/manage-domains/how-to-set-up-wildcard-subdomains

Comment: @Momergil link should be worked now. Can you try again ?